# Case statement in VHDL test bench takes decremented value

Tags: case, vhdl, test-bench

I am working on a project using VHDL and I am facing a problem during one of my test benches. I testing all input combinations for a combinational component using a for loop in my stimulus process, but I have a case statement inside the foor loop which is not behaving the way I wish it to.

This is the code segment that isn't behaving the way I want it to:

```vhdl
for i in 0 to 20 loop
    case opcode is
        when "01001" | "01010" | "01100" | "01110" | "10000" =>
            d <= '0';
            wait for period;
            d <= '1';
        when "00010" | "00100" | "00101" | "00110" | "10001" | "10010" | "10011" =>
            d <= '1';
        when others =>
            d <= '0';
    end case;
    wait for period;
    opcode <= opcode + 1;

end loop;
```

As an example, I expect `d` to become `1` when `opcode` is `00010`. In the simulation, however, `d` becomes `1` when `opcode` becomes `00011` rather than `00010` (same for all other cases too), as if the value the case statement checks is decremented by 1. I changed `opcode` inside the case statement to `opcode+1` and it worked correctly. I do know that VHDL is a hardware description language and that its behavior differs from a programming language, but I still cannot wrap my head around why this is happening, and would like an explanation.

Comment: Instead of `wait for period` try `wait until rising_edge(clk)` instead.  I suspect you have a delta race

Comment: The component I am testing is combinational, I do not have a clock.

Comment: I have looked up 'delta race' and it in fact was a delta race, but in my simulation code! The value of `opcode` is updated but still not sensed by stimulus process so the case statement checks for outdated `opcode`, and its only updated once I hit a `wait for period`. I inserted a `wait for 0 ns;` at the start of my for loop to trigger the new delta cycle manually and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update to the `opcode` signal is not 'sensed' by the simulator until it hits a wait statement. Adding `wait for 0 ns;` at the start of the loop fixes the problem.